# Is Appian development more or less marketable than .NET development?

Tags: career-development, career-switch

I got my degree in Computer Science two years ago. Since then, I've been working at a very small company doing something unconventional. I spend, at most, 20% of my time doing traditional object-oriented application development on a very small team that does not use Agile. The rest is more soft-skills related.

**Job A:** Appian developer. Take ownership of small projects and turn them around quickly. Client-facing position. Pays 22% more than current position.

**Job B:** .NET developer. Become part of a larger project and develop alongside a team. Has a security clearance. Pays 7% more than current position, but also includes very generous health insurance and paid leave policies that Job A does not offer.

I've had some people tell me just do what I love. I love making stuff that works. It sounds like I could do that with either job. After that, I love having job security, the ability to know I will be able to move on to a new job if need be, and the highest possible future earning potential, even if that comes at the sacrifice of immediate earnings.

What would you do in my place?

Comment: I don't think we can really answer this. I'd always go for the bigger money all else being equal.

Comment: We can't say what we'd do in your place because we aren't you and have different requirements/desires for a position.  For me I'd skip Appian because it seems to be a proprietary platform.  OTOH security clearances can be gold in the right situation and .NET has a wider application.

Comment: That's the first time I hear of appian...

Comment: Third option: take Job B (for the reasons in the answer by @Matthew Gaiser), but use the higher offer from Job A as leverage to try to get a bit more money in Job B. The script is basically “This seems like a great company and team, I think I will learn a lot and have a lot to contribute. However, it’s a big difference in salary - is there anything you can do to lessen the gap?” They will likely  talk about the great benefits and you can respond that yes they’re great, but it’s still kind of a big gap. If the make a better offer and you want it, make sure to accept appreciatively.

Answer (score 6):

**The .Net job**

1. **Appian is a single proprietary platform.** I would not compare it to a programming language. It is more like a specific framework with its own programming language. Imagine knowing only Flutter and Dart or perhaps even ColdFusion. That limits you essentially to a niche of the app development space. .Net can be used for virtually anything.
2. **Clearances can be very valuable.** You don't say where you are located, but having a clearance can open up a lot of further opportunities down the road.
3. **Team development is a different game from individual projects.** There are a lot of things you can get away with as an individual that are ruinous on a large team. It is a lot easier to go from team to solo than the other way.
4. **Do you want to be focused on the openly discount option?** Low code is basically the software development option for people wanting cheaper development options at the cost of flexibility. I would be wary of seeking a high salary in an area where people seek cheap.

EDIT: Kilisi has a point that I want to address. What does a senior Appian developer earn compared to a senior C# developer? Does the position of senior Appian developer even exist? As the Appian job may not have great job prospects 5 years down the road, even if the platform survives.

Comment: I agree with everything in this answer, but 15% pay difference is quite a bit. Dotnet isn't going to go away anytime soon.

Comment: @Kilisi the"very generous health insurance and paid leave policies" may close that 15% difference in salary significantly.

Comment: @alroc maybe, maybe not, but you can 100% spend cash in your hand.

Comment: @Kilisi I understand that .NET isn't going away soon, BUT my .NET skills may if I take the Appian job, which makes the rest somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: This is a really helpful and in-depth answer. I had a feeling this was the way to go, but it's nice to get some advice from someone with more experience. I live in the DC metro area, so the clearance is certainly valuable (and even jobs outside of this area can require a clearance).

Answer (score 2):

Do a quick search on stack exchange for the number of Appian questions versus the number of .Net questions, and then work out for yourself which is more marketable. (Hint - it’s not Appian :-))

Comment: This doesn't prove anything though, does it? It could be that Appian is much more popular and more marketable but easier to learn/ more self-explanatory/ better documented. It could be that Appian is newer than .net, etc. etc. Not a good answer.

Comment: @BigMadAndy seriously...?

Comment: @BigMadAndy, I work in this field and Appian is completely unknown to me. It's definitely a dead-end. Believe me.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, that's not the point here though, is it? The answer implies that the number of stack exchange on Appian is much lower than the number of questions on .net, so .net is more marketable. The conclusion is illogical.

Comment: LinkedIn in the UK list 58 Appian jobs (https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=101165590&keywords=appian&location=United%20Kingdom&originalSubdomain=uk) as opposed to 8742 .Net jobs (https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=101165590&keywords=.net&location=United%20Kingdom&originalSubdomain=uk). Are you still seriously trying to suggest that Appian is a better choice from a marketability/career development point of view...?